# Regex to match last part of file path

Tags: regex, csv

I have a .csv file of strings containing paths to certain files. I want to capture all filenames from that file.

Example data:

```
/second/path/to/something-4-5_4.pdf,
/path/to/certain/file.pdf
randomnoise,
```

What I want to capture:
all occurences of words after slash and ending with .pdf, in this case:

```
something-4-5_4.pdf
file.pdf
```

What I tried:

```
\/(.*)\.pdf
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0Xlpwf/1)

This unfortunately catches everything between / and .pdf, the whole path. I have trouble coming up with condition for it to catch the part I want

Comment: Replace `.*` with `[^\/]*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that the `.` pattern matches any char other than line break chars. You need to restrict the pattern to only match any chars other than a slash.

There are several solutions, including

```
\/([^\/]*\.pdf)
[^\/]*\.pdf
[^\/]*\.pdf$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VgU549/1). *Details*:

- `\/([^\/]*\.pdf)` matches `/`, then captures one or more chars other than `/` as many as possible and then `.pdf` into Group 1
- `[^\/]*\.pdf` just matches one or more chars other than `/` as many as possible and then `.pdf`
- `[^\/]*\.pdf$` works the same as above, but also makes sure the `pdf` is at the end of string.